# Cookies not working on IE11 on windows 10

Tags: cookie

Im testing our site on BrowserStack and it works in all browsers but Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10.

I can't add products to the cart and Magento is is saying I must enable cookies in the browser but I have!  Also cookies are working on other sites, for example the demo site we bought our theme for.

When I go to the site below it says cookies are enabled
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled

Not sure what to do?  Could it have something to do with my server or magento configuration?

We have Magento 1.9.2 running on an NGINX / HHVM server on a AWS ec2 box with Ubuntu 14.04

**Update**

I noticed that if I change *Use HTTP Only* to *NO* in [System > Configuration > General > Web](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#configuration/general/web.html%3FTocPath%3DConfiguration%2520Reference%7CGeneral%7C_____2) I can now add things to the cart and cookies seem to be working but the browser is still redirected enable-cookies CMS-page if the click on enable cookies in the Cookie notice at the bottom of the page.
[image]